# How to lemmatize whole corpus in R in faster way than mine approach

Tags: r, text-mining, lemmatization

I was trying different things to lemmatize huge corpus of words using different techniques in R language. Finally, I managed to use a package `koRpus` which is the wrapper for `TreeTagger` application.

`content.cc` is my corpus containing near 7000  documents with average word number of about 300 words. I set the function:

```
lemmatizeCorpus <- function(x) {

  if (x != "") {
    words.cc <- treetag(x, treetagger="manual", format="obj",
                      TT.tknz=FALSE, lang="en",
                      TT.options=list(path="c:/TreeTagger", preset="en"))

    words.lm <- ifelse(words.cc@TT.res$token != words.cc@TT.res$lemma, 
                     ifelse(words.cc@TT.res$lemma != "<unknown>", words.cc@TT.res$lemma, words.cc@TT.res$token),
                     words.cc@TT.res$token)

    content.w <- toString(paste(words.lm, collapse = " "))

  }
}
```

and executed that way:

```
content.lw <- sapply(X = content.cc$content, FUN = function(x) lemmatizeCorpus(x), USE.NAMES = F)
```

It brings the desired effect - changes words which have its root in the TT dictionary, and, what's important here, leaves the hierarchy the same as in the corpus (number of document, words positions, words number). The problem is this works for about an hour (on my rather slow machine, but it's not important on what cp it runs).

I tried to merge the whole corpus into one char matrix: `stri_extract_all_words(content.cc$content)` and applied the corpus as a whole in `treetag` function. It was faster in about 5x (the same function body), but I got lost trying find indices for which words belongs to which document, because the number of extracted words by `stri` and performed by `treetag` differed quite a bit. That loop is stable.

Another try was using stemmer from `tm` package, which is popular and help and solutions can be found on this forum also, but it reaches regex memory limit very fast and going into looping throws the same effect as current approach.

All I need is some suggestions what can I do with it? Can I? Maybe it's not possible to speed up the things because `TreeTagger` just works that way and can't be faster. I know it's challenging. Using `sapply` for example the result is about 2x faster then pure loop, so it's some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand the code completely, because of lack of familiarity with the API's you mentioned. But if I understood your problem statement, you basically need to lemmatize a corpus, or have the entire string/sentences lemmatized.

Did you try out library *'textstem'*?

```
library(textstem)
lemmatize_strings("He quit lazing around and actively to activities like running, aerobics and swimming", dictionary = lexicon::hash_lemmas)
```

The output is...

> [1] "He quit laze around and actively to activity like run, aerobics and swim"

You could thus try to first lemmatize your entire input, and generate a corpus for it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).